# bash regex: asterisk gives ambiguous search results with grep

Tags: shell, grep, quoting, wildcards

I am using a simple text file to test the `*` meta-character through grep.
The text file is as below:

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111

d
da
daa
daaa

b
bc
bcc
bccc
```

Now when I search digit 1 using grep like this:

```
grep 1* regex.txt
```

output is

```
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111

d
da
daa
daaa

b
bc
bcc
bccc
```

Even in the case of character 'd' the result is same with highlighted 'd' in red
BUT in the case of character 'a' & 'b' there is no output for the following search command:

```
grep a* regex.txt
grep b* regex.txt
```

AND the below commands give expected output

```
grep "a*" regex.txt
grep "b*" regex.txt
```

Why so? Why is `bash` partial towards the character 'd' and not to 'a' & 'b'

Comment: Without quotes `*` is expanded by shell path. If there is no output for `a*` try `echo a*` and you should see files with names started with `a` (same `b`)

Comment: 1. quote your regexps so the shell doesn't interpret them as wildcard globs.  2.  regexps are not wildcard globs.  `*` means zero-or-more of the last character/sub-expression.  It does **not** mean "followed by anything" as it does in a shell wildcard.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to add a second question. Post a new question instead. I also suggest you read a basic primer on regular expressions to understand how they work a bit better. Try http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the `a*` and `b*` are not quoted and, therefore, are expanded by the shell *before* being passed to `grep`. For example, consider this directory:

```
$ ls    
afile.txt bfile.txt regex.txt
```

If I try to run `grep a* regex.txt`, the `a*` will become `afile.txt` and that is what will be given as a search pattern to `grep`. We can use bash's debugging option (`set -x`) to demonstrate:

```
$ set -x
$ grep a* regex.txt
+ grep --color afile.txt regex.txt
```

The reason it worked for `d` and not for `a` or `b` is that you have a files or directories whose names start with `a` and `b` in your current directory. If you didn't, it would have worked:

```
$ ls
afile.txt bfile.txt regex.txt
$ grep a* regex.txt  ## no output, it's searching for 'afile.txt'
$ rm afile.txt       ## now there are no filenames starting with a
$ grep a* regex.txt
1
11
111
1111
11111
111111

d
da
daa
daaa

b
bc
bcc
bccc
```

To avoid this, ***always* quote your search patterns**:

```
grep "a*" regex.txt
```

Or

```
grep 'a*' regex.txt
```